# Admob ads are not appearing on xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

I am trying to place a google admob banner ad on a xamarin forms project but I cannot.
I have not tried from many sites. When I run the application on both the phone and the emulator, the colorful template of the ad appears at the bottom, but the ad does not. I also tried it with test id.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App6.CustomRenders;assembly=App6"  


             x:Class="App6.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

         <local:AdBanner WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="50"/>



    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**AdBanner.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App6.CustomRenders
{
    public class AdBanner : View
    {
        public enum Sizes { Standardbanner, LargeBanner, MediumRectangle, FullBanner, Leaderboard, SmartBannerPortrait }
        public Sizes Size { get; set; }
        public AdBanner()
        {
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Accent;
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

**AdBanner_Droid.cs (in Android)**

```
using System;
using App6;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using App6.CustomRenders;
using App6.Droid.CustomRenders;
using Android.Content;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdBanner), typeof(AdBanner_Droid))]
namespace App6.Droid.CustomRenders
{
    public class AdBanner_Droid : ViewRenderer
    {
        Context context;
        public AdBanner_Droid(Context _context) : base(_context)
        {
            context = _context;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                var adView = new AdView(Context);
                switch ((Element as AdBanner).Size)
                {
                    case AdBanner.Sizes.Standardbanner:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.Banner;
                        break;
                    case AdBanner.Sizes.LargeBanner:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.LargeBanner;
                        break;
                    case AdBanner.Sizes.MediumRectangle:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.MediumRectangle;
                        break;
                    case AdBanner.Sizes.FullBanner:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.FullBanner;
                        break;
                    case AdBanner.Sizes.Leaderboard:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.Leaderboard;
                        break;
                    case AdBanner.Sizes.SmartBannerPortrait:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner;
                        break;
                    default:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.Banner;
                        break;
                }
                // TODO: change this id to your admob id  
                adView.AdUnitId = "ca-app-p";

                var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                adView.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
                SetNativeControl(adView);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVUNA.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried using one of the test ad units? `adView.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"`

Comment: yes I tried both the test unit and my own real ad. neither happened.